# What is the correct way to create multiple apps in VueJS3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

The new VueJS is coming. I played around with it, but I have a problem.

```js
const HelloVueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!!'
    }
  }
}
Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('.demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div class="demo">one {{ message }}</div>
<!-- a lot of static html code -->
<div class="demo">two {{message}}</div>
```

The first instance is created fine, but the second isn't. How can I create multiple vue3 application on the same page?

Comment: One vue instance can only be mounted in one element

Answer (score 0):

```js
const HelloVueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!!'
    }
  }
}
Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount('.demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div class='demo'> 
one {{ message }}
////////////////////////
two {{message}}
</div>
```

you cant use the same id or class in 2 tag in same page , you should create the main tag an

Comment: same classes are allowed by html standard

Comment: thats true same id or class in 2 tag in same page but  inside template of vue js  you must define a general tag for youre vue instans 
then you set general id or class in the general tag of vue js